# angularjs custom sum filter doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

im trying to do sum  operation on my table  Like

```
Item   Price
abc    10
xyz    20
Ites=>2   Price=>30
```

For this i wrote simple custome filter

```
.filter('SumOfAmt', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(value[key]);
```

**Html code**

```
  <form name="form1" ng-submit="SaveDb(form1.$valid)" novalidate>

   <b>cost</b><input type="number"  ng-model="cost" required />
</form>
```

This is my Table when user enter in form it display in table

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="Emp in EmployeeList">
 <td>{{Emp.EmpName}}</td>
                        <td>{{Emp.Cost | currency}}</td>
                    </tr>
               This is {{EmployeeList|SumOfAmt:'Cost'}}
            </table>
```

Comment: With the help of this [library](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) you can write `{{EmployeeList | map : 'Cost' | sum}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what's wrong?

With your custom filter you can get the right sum, you just need to return sum:

```
.filter('SumOfAmt', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(value[key]);
        });
        return sum;
    };
});
```

But another alternative is:

```
.filter('SumOfAmt', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;
        return data.map(function(a){return parseInt(a[key])}).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    };
});
```